# Android: Facebook social context API - getting mutual friends

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to obtain the mutual friends count and data (user id and name) by using the Facebook Social Context API from this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/social-context/v2.0

The example code from the documentation is shown below, where I have adapted it using the Facebook id that i need.

```
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/3003345?fields=context",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

However, my Log shows this error:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Syntax error "Expected end of string instead of "?"." at character 7: context?access_token="accesstoken"}, isFromCache:false}
```

(I replaced the access token with "accesstoken")

Anyone knows the solution to this? I have been stuck for days. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with GraphRequest class, so I'll write for it.

GraphRequest will make URL like this

```
  ...facebook.com/3003345?fields=context?access_token=...
```

instead of

```
  ...facebook.com/3003345?fields=context&access_token=...
```

as it should be.

Solution:

```
  GraphRequest request =  GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(session, 3003345,...);

  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

  parameters.putString("fields", "context");

  request.setParameters(parameters);

  request.executeAsync();
```